# Is a head-mounted lamp better than a candle for bedikas chometz?

Tags: halacha, passover, technology, lighting, bedikas-chametz

A [LED or Xenon lamp attached to the head](http://www.opticsplanet.net/streamlight-buckmasters-camo-trident-led-xenon-headlamp-61070.html) (link shows example) seems to be ideal for bedikas chometz and superior to a candle? Do contemporary poskim offer a view?

Comment: I've always been told that you should burn everything you use in the search. "Kabalistic reasons"

Comment: http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Hebrew_sources_for_using_a_flashlight_for_Bedikat_Chametz

Answer (score 5):

http://www.thehalacha.com/attach/Volume3/SpecialIssue.pdf

> In places where it is hard to check one may use a flashlight. (Refer
>   to Natei Gavriel 1:17:19, Chazzon Ovadia Pesach 1:page 138:2:footnote
>   13 in depth, Otzer Ha’halochos page 116:12, Horav Eider Shlita’s sefer
>   on Hilchos Pesach page 86, Shevet Ha’Levi 1:136:page 137, Shevus
>   Yitzchok Pesach page 35 quoted the opinion of Horav Shlomo Zalman
>   Aurbach zt”l, see Siddur Pesach K’hilchoso page 159. In places where
>   one cannot go with a candle i.e.  under beds or in a closest, then one
>   should use a flashlight etc. (Be’er Moshe 6:K.A. 63). Horav Yisroel
>   Belsky Shlita does not use a flashlight.  Refer to Yabea Omer 4:40,
>   Bedikas Chometz U’biuro page 176:footnote 36.)
>
> However, the custom is to use a wax candle for the bedika, (Hilchos
>   Chag B’Chag page 75:5)  therefore, one should start off using a wax
>   candle and then he may use a flashlight, etc. (Horav Eider Hilchos
>   Shlita’s sefer on Hilchos Pesach page 86 in the name of Horav Aaron
>   Kotler zt”l.)

Answer (score 2):

The other way of looking at it is that a candle is sufficient--that is, you need to search as well as you practically can by using a candle, you don't need to go beyond that level of search.
Source: @Gershon Gold's answer noting that

> Horav Yisroel Belsky Shlita does not use a flashlight.

Yes, I know the downsides of seeing chometz in the home after Pesach starts.

Also the start of @Gershon's answer:

> In places where it is hard to check one **may** use a flashlight.

In other words, a flashlight is not required for the search.

We can imagine a continuum of inspecting that has "search by a candle" near one end and "move all the furniture for a minute inspection with the brightest lights you have" at the other end. Either could have been specified by the Halacha. But only the first one was.

Remember that Judaism does not have a blanket rule that "greater piety equals greater good."

Summary: no need to use more than a candle for searching. (But ask your own Rabbi for personalized advice to follow.)