# Can you use an LED light array for searching for chametz?

Tags: chametz-leaven, lighting

Would this [portable LED light array which has 30 LEDs spread over an area of around 6 inches by 1 inch](http://www.beamled.com/biard-30-led-battery-operated-work-light.html?gclid=CLbo48Kfrr0CFdShtAod-3oAPA)  be suitable for bedikat chametz? If not, why would a traditional [beeswax candle](http://www.chabad.org/holidays/passover/pesach_cdo/aid/117217/jewish/Search-for-Chametz.htm) be better? The LED array would be far more effective.

Comment: dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13239/759

Comment: @Double AA The "LED light array" is a more extended light source (less focussed) than the head lamp.

Comment: It's not clear in either case that the scope of the question is a specific angled light beam. Perhaps you should clarify that with some edits?

Answer (score 4):

Rav Moshe Mintz, a posek in Ner Israel, told me that you can ideally use any light that can be focused in one area (as opposed to the sunlight or the main light in a room, which lights up the entire room), as the purpose of the candle at night is to contrast with the dark in the rest of the room.

Comment: What does "focussed" and "one area" mean in this context? The LED light array in the question would illuminate an area of say several square feet.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok Candles aren't so laser-sharp either.  It means a small area which will still leave an unlit area around it.

Answer (score 1):

Rav Moshe Heinemann writes in [Hilchos Pesach](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1798814862) (1:2):

> The Gemara says we use a נר for חיפוש, searching for חמץ (Pesachim
> 7b). In order to be considered a נר, you need to have fuel, a כלי
> to hold the fuel, and a wick which draws the fuel from the כלי to
> produce a flame. Even if you have a fluorescent light which has fuel
> in the electricity and the bulb acting as the כלי, you still lack the
> wick. Therefore, you cannot use fluorescent light bulbs for נרות שבת.
> Frosted bulbs versus unfrosted bulbs doesn’t make a difference except
> by הבדלה where we say בורא מאורי האש to see the different colors of
> the fire. When the bulb is frosted, then you cannot see the different
> colors. However, you can see the different colors of the tungsten
> filament in an unfrosted incandescent bulb. An LED light seems to be a
> מחלוקת whether it has a filament or not. I don’t know how that can be
> a מחלוקת, but if an LED bulb has a filament then you may use it for
> בדיקת חמץ, and if it doesn’t then you should not use it. בדיעבד make
> the ברכה on a candle, search for חמץ with it a little bit, then use an
> LED or fluorescent bulb.

The LED light array *may* be fine, but Rav Heinemann explains why using a candle may be better since it contains all three aspects of a "ner": fuel, utensil to hold the fuel, and a wick to draw the fuel from the utensil.